# Python can't open link

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to open instagram.com and then have it redirect to the login screen. However, it opens instagram.com but won't go to the login screen and just sits at the main page.

```
def login(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
    time.sleep(2)
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher/']")
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
    user_name_elem.clear()
    user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
    password_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    password_elem.clear()
    password_elem.send_keys(self.password)
    password_elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Ok. What is your question?

Comment: How can I fix it so it goes to instagram.com/login when it finds the login button?

Comment: Why not opening straight the right link on the first call, such as in `driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")`?

Comment: You can also use selenium built-in method to wait until load, using `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`, and writing, instead of `time.sleep(2)`, something such as: 
`WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "NAME_OF_A_VALID_ELEMENT")))`

Answer (score -1):

sites like Instagram and Facebook filter all terminal access (for security reasons), you can change your terminal browser name to a common one like chrome or firefoxe and try to add delays between actions to make it seem more human

Comment: Selenium does not use "terminal access". It uses a real web browser.